# How can I remove the section from the last slide?

Tags: beamer

I want to put some slides at the end of my presentation in the case someone will ask something to them. Therefore I want to delete the introduction in the example below from the navigation bar. How can I get that to work?

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\title{Test}
\author{Alex XYZ}
\institute{University XYZ}
\date{20.01.16}

\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{System Design and Database}
Content of database.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The best solution is to start a new part with `\part{}`.

Comment: @Sigur: I do not understand what do u mean. Where do I have to start with `\part{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to start a new part with `\part{}`.

```
\part{}
\begin{frame}{System Design and Database}
Content of database.
\end{frame}
```

[image]